# Phonegap 3.5 audio not playing on Android, even with correct file type and path? Code 1 error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, audio

I've been trying to implement the Phonegap Media plugin to playback an audio file.

I understand I'll need to refer to the correct file path (android_asset/www/...) and use an .amr file as per the docs but it's still returning with a code: 1 error, which I believe has something to do with a disruption in getting the file.

```
function sound(){

    var backgroundMusic = null; 
    var musicPlaying = false; 

    function playAudio(){

        function getPhoneGapPath() {
            var devicePlatform = device.platform;
            if (devicePlatform === "iOS") {
                path = "";
            } else if (devicePlatform === "Android" || devicePlatform === 'android') {
                path = "/android_asset/www/";
            }
            return path;
        };

        var backgroundMusic = new Media(getPhoneGapPath() + 'audio/bg.amr', success, error);

        function success(){
            backgroundMusic.release();
            alert('success');
        }
        function error(e){
            alert(getPhoneGapPath() + 'audio/bg.amr');
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        }

        if (!musicPlaying) {
            backgroundMusic.play();
            musicPlaying = true; 
            $(".audio-off").css('display', 'block');
            $(".audio-on").css('display', 'none');
        }
        else if (musicPlaying){
            backgroundMusic.stop();
            musicPlaying = false;
            $(".audio-on").css('display', 'block');
            $(".audio-off").css('display', 'none');
        };
    }

    $(".audio-on, .audio-off").on("touchstart", function() {
        playAudio();
    });

}

window.onload = function() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady(){

    sound();

//other code...

}
```

After reading so many questions and tutorials I can't see where I've gone wrong. The media plugin is also definitely included in my config.xml as well.

I'm testing on my Nexus 5 with Lollipop 5.0.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :-)

Comment: is your bg.amr in android_asset/www/audio path. I think your code is ok.Can you check the file path once?

Comment: Thanks for looking over it @Banik, appreciate your help so far. Here's a screenshot showing my file paths, just incase it's wrong  - http://oi58.tinypic.com/ztvko0.jpg

Comment: I just ran your code,it worked perfectly.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using the PhoneGap Desktop App, so now I'm starting to question whether it supports the media plugin if there doesn't seem to be a problem with the code. Thanks @Banik.